# RichTextUploadingField not reflecting to models

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

So I have been following the step by step from this website to integrating-ckeditor-in-django but it is not reading/ reflecting in my models.py

Here is the step by step that I have followed:

Step 1:

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

Step 2:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    ..................]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

#...
SITE_ID = 1

####################################
    ##  CKEDITOR CONFIGURATION ##
####################################

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    },
}

###################################
```

Step 3:
in the main projects folder urls.py:

```
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

in the models.py

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextField, RichTextUploadingField

class ModelClass:
    ## content = models.TextField()
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
```

It is getting an error when migrating

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'RichTextField' from 'ckeditor_uploader.fields' (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\ckeditor_uploader\fields.py)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `RichTextUploadingField` belongs to `from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField`, but the `RichTextField` to the `ckeditor.fields`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichTextUploadingField` belongs to `from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField`, but the `RichTextField` to the `ckeditor.fields`. You thus import these with:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
```

In your question you do not use the `RichTextUploadingField`, so in that case you can remove the second import.

Comment: it is working just fine now but I have a question in the models both imports are showing as if there is an error underlined in red. is there a reason?

Comment: @A_K: likely this is because you never used the `RichTextUploadingField`, in that case you do not have to import this.